# Restore QGIS layer after saving

Tags: qgis

We are working on a QGIS layer contained in a project in `.qgz` format. So I did a deletion of the attribute table of a project layer. How can I recover the data that is not in the database backuped.

Comment: There are options in Windows, probably at WinServer thing, which let you restore changed/deleted data.

Comment: Thanks, please Erik can you be more explicit ?

Comment: "Previous Versions" Windows https://abletp.net/set-up-and-use-previous-versions-of-files/ (one of the quickest ways to get files back if deleted/corrupt if setup correctly before   incidents happen)

Comment: It's unclear if you remove the layer from the QGIS project or if you delete the datasource  could you tell us exactly how you "did a deletion of the attribute table of a project layer"?

Comment: By the attribute table, edition, resverse selection and delet. Yes  i did a "deletion of the attribute table of a project layer"

Comment: So if your data are in a file based format and you are using windows the solution in @Mapperz comment is your best bet...

Comment: No Windows (Linux/Mac) a NAS can do this same action. (example Diskstation does this for all OS's)